# HTTP Error 500.19 Internal Server Error after hosting angular 4 application in IIS

Tags: angular, typescript, web-config

I know I am not the first to ask this question here ,I could find lot of solutions related to my issue but nothing is solved my issue .,

Image :

[image]

Web.config

```
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

index.html

```
<base href ="/eCommerceWebsite/">
```

Physical Path in IIS

```
C:\eCommerceWebsite
```

Can anyone tell me where I did the mistakes and what I need to change here

**Edit :**

Image1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Updated web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/eCommerceWebsite" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Edit 2 :**

[image]

Comment: 1. Ensure the AppPool user has read permissions on your directory C:\eCommerceWebsite
2. Go to IIS Manager, select your website in the left pane and then double click on the HttpHandlers in right pane to check if all handlers list show up or any error is displayed

Comment: Please see my edited post and tell me where I did the mistakes @MohsinMehmood

Comment: Check do you have url rewrite IIS extension installed on the server? You can install it using WebPlatform installer

Comment: It is working fine in my local IIS server ,when I host it in another system's IIS it throws the above error .I am confusing with it @MohsinMehmood

Comment: Have you verified that IIS url rewrite module is installed on the host server

Comment: @MohsinMehmood yes I have checked it ,it's already there .

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I could not find the exact problem ,and moreover tried all the solutions from stackoverflow  which related to my issue

Comment: Is your app pool running under app pool identity or some other system user? Can you share app pool settings screenshot? Ensure the app pool user has read access to physical directory.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood please check the updated image of app pool settings

Answer (score 10):

Just to keep in register here. You need to install the [IIS URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), this is an IIS Extension to your <**rewrite**> routes works. This extension fixed my problem with IIS.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to IIS Manager, select your website in left pane and check you have Url Rewrite and Authentication icons on the right

[image]

2. Double click on the Authentication icon, then right click on "Anonymous Authentication" and click edit

[image]

3. Select Application Pool Identity radio button
   [image]
4. For your Application Pool set "Enable 32 bit Applications" to true
5. Now go to C: drive right click on your website directory **eCommerceWebsite** and then click Security and then edit.
6. Click Add and then in the object name you have to type in the AppPool identity user which has the format "IIS AppPool{AppPoolName}" e.g. in screenshot I have "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" for defaultAppPool. Next click check names and then assign "Modify" permissions.

[image]